# Mapping partial column values using Toplink

Tags: java, toplink

Suppose I have a list of IDs as follows:

     `EmployeeID
      -------
       ABCD
       AECD
       ABDF
       ACDF
       ACDE`

I have a need to read the distinct values from a list of codes, while selecting only the first two characters of the column. 
In other words, its similar to using the following query:

`SELECT DISTINCT LEFT (EmployeeID,2) FROM TABLE1`

My question is how do I map such a field in TOPLINK.

Note:I have created a class for the EmployeeID, but dont have an idea of mapping a partial field.

Comment: I have implemented a work around for this. 
Appreciate if anyone can guide the 'right way' to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... After looking at many workarounds, I seem to have a more suited solution.

I created an object for this particular scenario (the POJO has only the field for the holding the 2 Char ID, and its getter and setter methods).

During the mapping, I mapped the above field to the DB column in question (EmployeeID in the table described above).

Now I selected "Custom Queries" for the above object and entered the following query for "Read all" tab.

`SELECT DISTINCT LEFT (EmployeeID,2) AS EmploeeID FROM TABLE1`

All the read all operations on the object will now return the list of distinct first 2 characters of IDs.

Welcome anyone's opinion on this.